# Set Zyxel XS1920 as unmanaged switch

Tags: networking, switch, zyxel

I have a Zyxel XS1920 smart managed switch
https://www.zyxel.ch/de/support/download/201962_1/

I want to use it as a (very fast) unmanaged switch; like a QNAP QSW-1208.  So I don't need it to be smart, I just need it to be simple so I can plug it in to extend an existing network.

Can anyone advise in simple terms how I might do this?  I do have access to the Zyxel management interface; I just don't know what buttons to press.

I hope this question is clear but happy to provide any further information.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: clear the configuration and don't use it, then it's just a "dumb" switch

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that's what I expected!  
But the factory config appears to be a managed switch, managing a subnet on 192.168.1.1.  If there's a "dumb" switch setting, I'm missing it.  
I can't see anything in the manual either.  Perhaps I'm missing the obvious? https://www.zyxel.ch/de/support/download/201962_1/

Comment: no, you don't understand the point. it's default ip will be that, but can be changed to any value. this does not have anything to do what you want to do. A switch is not a router. It does not take care about what ip it has. you could plug the same device into decix and it will do the job - it might get a worse performance but it would work ;) take a note of [wiki about switches](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch)

Answer (score 0):

A managed switch just offers more features than a basic, unmanaged switch. If you don't want to use those features, simply don't. By default, a managed switch behaves just like an unmanaged one.

If there's some configuration already, reset it to factory default, set the admin password(s) to something secure and you're done. Still, there's some IP address for management, but you can just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you.  This seems clear; I'll give it a go.